# What is the algorithmic complexity of this function that calculates the minimum difference of values in a vector?

Tags: c++, algorithm, time-complexity

I have written a function that takes a vector of ints, and returns the minimum difference between two elements (ie, the difference of the elements that are nearest to one another).

I am trying to work out the algorithmic complexity. The first for loop iterates over all elements of the input (I'll call this N), which is linear complexity: O(n). The inner for loop iterates over N - 1 the first time, then N - 2, N - 3, ...  N - N + 2, N - N + 1, 0. So I don't think this algorithm is O(n^2). My guess is it is O(N * log(N)), is that correct?

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>

long int function(const std::vector<int> &Input)
{
    long int MinimumDifference = -1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < Input.size(); i++)
    {
        for(size_t j = i + 1; j < Input.size(); j++)
        {
            long int Difference = abs(static_cast<long int>(Input[i] - Input[j]));
            if(Difference < MinimumDifference || MinimumDifference < 0)
            {
                MinimumDifference = Difference;
            }
        }
    }

    return MinimumDifference;
}
```

**Edit:**
So the above is O(n^2), think I can achieve O(N * log(N)) by sorting the list first (using std::sort, which has O(N * log(N))), and then just iterate over the list to find the smallest difference.

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <vector>
£include <algorithm>

void function(const std::vector<int> &Input)
{
    std::vector<int> SortedInput = Input;
    std::sort (SortedInput.begin(), SortedInput.end());

    long int MinimumDifference = -1;

    for(size_t i = 0; i < SortedInput.size() - 1; i++)
    {
        long int Difference = abs(static_cast<long int>(SortedInput[i] - SortedInput[i + 1]));
        if(Difference < MinimumDifference || MinimumDifference < 0)
        {
            MinimumDifference = Difference;
        }
    }

    return MinimumDifference;
}
```

Comment: Note that if you want to improve O, you could sort the list first, then do a single pass through to get the smallest difference. This could get you O(nLog(n)) (depending on sort algorithm used).

Comment: You have to realise that even when an algorithm is `O(n^2)`, this doesn't necessarily mean there are precisely n^2 operations to be performed. Rather, it stands for `c * n^2`, where `c` can be any positive constant. In your case, `c=1/2`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A little algebraic manipulation tells us that

```
(n-1) + (n-2) + ... + 1 = n * (n+1) / 2
                        = n^2 / 2 + O(n)
```

so this algorithm's complexity is indeed `O(n^2)`

Comment: funny, I would have used `o(n^2)` (something small compared to) instead of O(n) (something the size of). Just different mindset but I agree with answer (was typing mine at the same time)

Comment: @Bruce: mixing Big-O and little-o notation is a good way to confuse people, though. Especially for people whose handwriting is as small as mine.

Comment: AFAIK, `n^2 + n = n^2 + o(n^2)` as `lim(n/n^2) = lim(1/n) = 0`. if `f(n)=O(y(n)) + o(y(n))` then `f(n) = O(y(n))`. On the contrary, if `f(n)=O(y(n)) + O(x(n))`, then you have to compare x and y to see which one weights most (which in your case is trivial as comparing n^2 to n is immediate)... Anyway, g'd answer and sorry for the comment spam.

Comment: @Bruce: actually, the tighter answer would be to use `θ(n^2)` since the complexity is bounded above and below by `n^2`. The definition of `f(n) in o(g(n))` is that for every real `k > 0`, then `|f(n)| < k . |g(n)|` so it would be inaccurate here. [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation#Family_of_Bachmann.E2.80.93Landau_notations)

Answer (score 0):

No, you're imbricating two loops of the "roughly same size", your complexity is `O(n^2/2)`
 = `O(n^2)`

To convince yourself, think that `sum(i) for i in [0,n] = n.(n+1)/2 = O(n^2/2) = O(n^2)` which is exactly what your doing.

To do some "complexity for newbies", just count the number of imbricated loops. If they iterate on base element, multiply by `n`, if they reduce the problem complexity by an order (split problem in halves), multiply by `log(n)`